# Finite morphism of varieties and noetherian ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm currently trying to "generalize" the definition of the degree of a morphism of (smooth) curves that I saw in class to higher dimensional varieties. So, I've been introduced to the concepts of dominant and finite morphisms and here's my problem:

In class, we said in class that $\overline{k}[X_1, \dots , X_n]$ is a noetherian ring, which implies that every ideal is finetly generated. Moreover, a morphism $\phi: V \longrightarrow W$ is said to be finite if $\overline{k}[V]$ (seen as a $\overline{k}[W]$-module) is finite-generated. Then, it seems to be always the case to me, by the noetherian property. Why am I wrong and why don't we need this hypothesis (having a finite morphism) with the degree of morphism of curves?

Thanks

Comment: It's late at night, but I'm guessing you've blurred the notions of finitely generated as an algebra vs. finitely generated as a module (e.g. $R[x]$ is generated by $x$ as an $R$-algebra but by $1,x,x^2,...$ as an $R$-module). As for curves, every morphism between curves is either constant or finite. In higher dimensions you can have contracted subvarieties of positive dimension, so e.g. a map between surfaces can be generically finite while still contracting a curve.

Comment: Mh yeah, I see what I did wrong now, thanks! However, would you mind to explain what you mean by a "contracted subvariety" please? Never heard of it before

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of blowing up? If not, I would read up on it. The simplest example is the blow up of $\mathbb A^2$ at the origin. The algebro-geometric way to think about this is that we consider the rational map $\mathbb A^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbb P^1$ which sends $(x,y) \mapsto (x:y)$; in other words, we send $x \ne (0,0)$ to the slope of the line connecting $x$ to $(0,0)$. This is, of course, undefined at the origin, so we consider the graph of the map in $\mathbb A^2 \times \mathbb P^1$ and take its closure $X$. The projection $X \to \mathbb A^2$...

Comment: ...is an isomorphism except over the origin, where there is an entire copy of $\mathbb P^1$ contracted to that single point. While you may have subvarieties contracting onto other subvarieties of lower (but still positive) dimension, all more elaborate examples are essentially variations on this theme.

Comment: Great! Now I get it! Thanks a lot